# WPF-Localization loc causes errors at design time

Tags: c#, wpf

I have followed this tutorial for my localization:

[WPF-Localization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30035/Simple-WPF-Localization)

At runetime everything works fine. But in Visual Studio I always get the errors:

```
Loc is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.

ResourceManager is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.
```

Therefore, I can't see the UI in Visual Studio. The tutorial uses a WPF Extension:

> You do not have to add any namespace references (like xmlns:loc="...") at the beginning of the XAML file, because the extension registers to the default Microsoft namespaces at startup (another idea I have borrowed from one of the other solutions).

Can someone helps me to fix this behaviour because I want to see my UI at 'design time'.

Thanks in advance.